# Yahoo Messenger API For Flex

Tags: apache-flex, api, actionscript, yahoo-messenger

Is there an API to implement Yahoo chat in Flex? Or at least some calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo Messenger API is not public, so you will not get an oficial API from them for sure.

Having said that, I don't know if there is an API available for FLEX. But I know one [for C](http://pidgin.im/download/source/) and one [for Java](http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/). Both of the open source. So you can try to implement Yahoo Messenger's protocol in FLEX.

Other thing you can try (although I don't know if it will meet your quality standards) is embedding a [WebPage](http://webmessenger.yahoo.com/) supporting Yahoo chat.

Good luck.

Comment: It's not about providing a chat feature, I actually need the list of contacts, who's on-line and who's not, etc...

Comment: I see... If you need contacts, there are some Open Source packages that will provide just that. But if you need presence status (who's online, who's not), I think you will need somehow login into YAHOO MESSENGER's service.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... but if there is an opensource java solution couldn't you use that to integrate it with Flex.  You can even use blazeds to send the messages from java to flex.

Comment: My web hosting plan doesn't support Java, maybe it's time that I find a better one.. Stack Overflow to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

There is now an SDK for Yahoo! Messenger.  The examples appear to be Java and PHP but the API itself is language agnostic.

http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/index.html